# Creating multiple if else statements

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Need help from a developer. I'm using an if else statement in my wordpress theme to render two different kinds of single post templates. Now I have to add another template. The present code is:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
    if ( in_category('1204') ) {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/1204-article.php');
        }

    else {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/regular-article.php');
        }
```

I want to include/append an additional statement that if in_category('345') then include 345-article.php else include regular-article.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `else if`, i.e.:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category('1204') ) 
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/1204-article.php');
}
else if ( in_category('345') ) 
{
      include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/345-article.php');
}
else 
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/regular-article.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks ryan.. what if I have to include two category id's? I tried putting in else if (in_category('345', '15') but it doesn't seem to work. Should I create another else if statement for category 15?

Comment: You could do that, but if the two categories lead to the same include, you could combine them with `else if (in_category('345') || in_category('15'))`. The `||` operator means OR.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if this solved your problem.